# how to create a jenkins pipeline for git pull

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, git-pull

I am trying to create a jenkins pipeline to do a git pull job, but while i am doing it is throwing the error
`fatal: could not read Password: No such device or address`

Comment: Without seeing your code no one can tell why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use Blue Ocean Plugin, Configure Source Code Repo using GUI. It will help to create Pipeline Code using GUI.
[Configure Repository in Blue Ocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fW6Q.png)